# Jsonp request using jquery to fetch bing web results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, bing

using this as a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx

can someone help me with the jquery call?

Do I actually pass in the javascript code for the callback, or just the name of the function?

```
BingSearch = function($bingUrl, $bingAppID, $keyword, $callBack) {

        $bingUrl = $bingUrl + "?JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=" + $callBack + "&Appid=" +                  $bingAppID + "&query=" + encodeURI($keyword) + "&sources=web";


$.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: $callBack,
            url: $bingUrl,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
                $callBack(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error: " + textStatus);
            }
        });

};
```

**Update**

Ok so I changed this to:

```
BingSearch = function(bingUrl, bingAppID, keyword, callback) {

    var url = bingUrl + "?method=?&JsonType=callback&Appid=" + bingAppID + "&query=" + encodeURI(keyword) + "&sources=web";

    $.getJSON(url, callback);

};
```

Calling it like:

```
BingSearch(url, appid, searchkeyword, function(searchresults) {

    alert('yes!');
};
```

Still getting the 'invalid label' error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use do jsonp with jQuery, replace the `JsonCallback=UserCallback` with `JsonCallback=?`. jQuery will then handle it like a regular $`.ajax()` request.

I suggest starting out with [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get used to the Bing API and moving back to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) when your ready to integrate it with your application.

Using the example from the [Bing API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx):

```
var apikey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
var url = 'http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId='+apikey+'&Version=2.2&Market=en-US&Query=testign&Sources=web+spell&Web.Count=1&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Answer (score 1):

`jsonp:` needs to be set to a string (I think it can also be left out), as this is just the name of the dynamically created function used to receive the JSONP.

But the formal parameter $callBack needs to be a reference to a function, so either you use

```
function callback(result){ /*processResultHere*/ }

BingSearch(..,..,.., callback);
```

or

```
BingSearch..,..,.., function(result){ /*processResultHere*/ });
```

And just so you know it, the excessive use of $ really hurts my eyes :)

Also, function names beginning with a capital should be reserved for 'classes', as many syntax checkers will complain on functions with capitals being called without `new` in front..

Comment: Yes $callBack is a reference to a function (anonymous function like you presented in your 2nd code snippet).  still getting a 'invalid label' error, it says 'invalid label' that spits out the json response from bing (in firebug)

Comment: But did you modify your `jsonp:` property? In your code you have it set to a function reference while it needs to be set to a string.

Comment: If you monitor the traffic using HttpFox or something, then you should see that the url used for the script request has the form of http://....&callback=[namefrom jsonp]

Comment: invalid label is something that is related to running `eval({"prop":"value"}); as the {} is interpreted as a block statement instead of an object literal. Sounds like jQuery isn't wrapping it in a () before eval'ing it..